# Yet another "add login" question... trying to add a login forces me to logout and in with the other

Tags: support

I browsed several of the threads here on meta about this subject and didn't find anyone experiencing quite the same issue that I'm having, though there seem to be several threads about similar issues so I might just be missing it.

I have an SO account, under the same name as the account on this meta site, and a few others under the SE umbrella. The account is tied to a gmail account that I no longer use, so I would like to add a login which is email address agnostic. Initially, if I remember correctly, this wasn't an option. Now, if I understand correctly, you can create a general StackExchange account and use that throughout the whole network.

I wanted to create a StackExchange account, add it to my current account, then remove the old, unneeded gmail association from the account.

What happened:

- Go to my profile, click 'add logins'
- In popup, click 'add more logins'
- On new page, click Stack Exchange account
- Page cycles, and says "You're already logged in with xxx.  Would you like to log out and log in with yyy" where yyy is my stackexchange account and xxx is the only account I actually care about.
- I've tried clicking yes, and it does what it says and logs me out of one account and into another.
- I've also tried clicking no (or cancel or whatever), and it just takes me back to the profile page, having accomplished nothing of note.

The stackexchange account was created on a previous attempt to go through the process but instead of clicking the SE logo to login, I clicked something that indicated it would create a new SE account.

I don't really want to have multiple accounts...nor do I want to use google or facebook or anything else to log into StackOverflow. What am I missing about this process?

Thanks, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same problem, and I solved it by:

1. Logging out of the SE-account (ie, the one using SE OpenID).
2. In the main account (here: your google one) 'add new login'
3. There, add your SE OpenID
4. Both accounts get merged.

While steps 2 to 3 are what you already tried, the most important one is step 1: If it recognizes you as still being logged in with the SE-account, it merely switches between them.